# How to divide a variable with delimiter into several rows in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, delimiter, divide

I have the follow data:

```
Name Scores 
A    93/90/100
B    70/90/80
C    80/20/40/30
D    60/60
E    100/100/0/60/80
F    0/20/40/50
```

The only rule here is ">=60: pass", "<60: fail". No matter how many score they have.

But, I want to keep the record of "fail" if they have any. Thus the result should be:

```
A    Pass
B    Pass
C    Pass/Fail
D    Pass
E    Pass/Fail
F    Fail
```

The only idea I have is to divide Scores into several rows:

```
Name Scores 
A    93
A    90
A    100
B    70
B    90
B    80
C    ...
```

And then, transfer them into

```
data Score;
    set Score;
    if Scores>=60 then indicator = 'Pass';
    if Scores<60 then indicator = 'Fail';
run;

Name Scores 
A    Pass
A    Pass
A    Pass
B    Pass
B    Pass
B    Pass
C    ...
```

Then delete duplicate, and do the inverse of the first step.

```
A    Pass
B    Pass
C    Pass/Fail
D    Pass
E    Pass/Fail
F    Fail
```

But I still have no idea if SAS/SQL can do this...

Comment: Never, ever store data as dash separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Each of your proposed steps is quite simple. You should make an attempt at doing this yourself before asking for help, and post your code when you do.

Comment: @user667489, I typed the only code I can. And I found one https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Splitting-variable-into-multiple-rows/td-p/16237 doing the similar thing. I don't know how to apply this to all the elements in the column. (I am sorry that I don't know how to use array in SAS)

Comment: Shouldn't 'E' has 'Pass' as an indicator as none of the values is <60?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing this:

```
data have;
infile cards truncover;
input Name $ Scores $50.;
cards;
A    93/90/100
B    70/90/80
C    80/20/40/30
D    60/60
E    100/100/0/60/80
F    0/20/40/50
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  do i = 1 to count(scores,'/') + 1;
    score = input(scan(scores,i,'/'),3.);
    if score >= 60 then pass = 1;
                   else fail = 1;
  end;
  length result $9;
  if pass and not(fail) then result = 'Pass';
  else if fail and not(pass) then result = 'Fail';
  else result = 'Pass/Fail';
  keep name scores result;
run;
```

Comment: What if I have 600 intervals (instead of 2 Pass or Fail) in your case... ?

Comment: Read the documentation for arrays and learn how to use them. Then, if necessary, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Explanation is in comments before each step of the query.I have changed 60 to 50 for 'E' to get in line with what you wanted as output.

```
/*********Input sample dataset***********/
data have;
  input Name $ Scores $20.;
datalines;
A    93/90/100
B    70/90/80
C    80/20/40/30
D    60/60
E    100/100/0/60/50
F    0/20/40/50
;

run;

/*******Getting number of required column for each row*******/
data have1;
set have;
no_of_col=countw(scores);
run;

/***Getting maximun number of required columns and storing them in a macro****/
proc sql noprint;
Select max(no_of_col) into: max_col
from
have1;
quit;

%LET MAX_COL = &MAX_COL;

/*****Using array to divide score in columns and then creating pass/fail column for each value of score columns*/
Data have2;
set have1;
array indicator $20. indicator1-indicator&max_col;
array temp  score1-score&max_col;
do i=1 to dim(TEMP);
        temp[i]=scan(scores,i,'/');
        IF temp[i]>=60 then indicator[i]= 'Pass';
        IF temp[i]<60 and temp[i]<> . then indicator[i] = 'Fail';
end;
DROP I NO_OF_COL scores score1-score&max_col;
run;

/***************Transposing to get indicators as column values for names**************/
proc transpose data=have2 out=outdata(drop=_name_);
by Name notsorted;
var indicator:;
run;
/***********Getting distinct values of pass/fail for a Name**********/
proc sql;
Create table have3 as
Select distinct a.* from
outdata a
where col1 not=" ";
quit;

/*********transpose pass/Fail column back as column values*/
proc transpose data=have3 out=outdata2;
by name notsorted;
var col1;
run;

/*******Getting indicator using 'CATS(to concatenate)'***********/
Data want (Keep=Name indicator);
set outdata2;
format indicator $20.;
indicator=" ";
array col $20. col1-col2;
do i=1 to dim(col);
indicator=compress(cats(col[i],"/",indicator));
end;
if substr(indicator,1,1)="/" then indicator=substr(indicator,2,length(indicator)-2);
else indicator=substr(indicator,1,length(indicator)-1);
drop i;
run;

My Output:-

Name    indicator
A        Pass
B        Pass
C        Pass/Fail
D        Pass
E        Pass/Fail
F        Fail
```

Let me know if you have any questions